# java.time.Instant (1.8) is thread safe?

Tags: java, java.time.instant

```
Instant instant;
void updateBy(){
   instant = Instant.now();
}
```

if yes, How to prove Instant is thread safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs for [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) under the implementation notes:

> This class is immutable and thread-safe.

Comment: thank you for your quick response; I found same in java doc.
is there any way we can prove that?

Answer (score 2):

> How to prove Instant is thread safe?

Analyze (using sound mathematical / formal methods) the source code to prove that it meets all of the requirements for thread safety. That is the only way to **prove** something is thread-safe.

You can't prove this by testing.

You can test non-thread-safe code any way you want and have the safety tests pass.  But that doesn't prove anything.  The tests may still fail on a different OS platform, or a different (possibly future) releases of Java.

(You can prove *by testing* is that something is NOT thread-safe.  If the test shows undisputable symptoms of non-thread-safe behavior, that is an "existence proof".)

This should be moot for the `Instant` class.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) *specifies* that the `Instant` class is thread-safe.  Unless you have a specific reason to believe that the class is not thread-safe (which would be **a genuine JVM bug**) then it is advisable to not waste your time looking for things that probably don't exist.

Comment: Bit of a leap from a mistake in the javadocs to a genuine JVM bug.

Comment: Not in this case.  The javadoc is a clear, unambiguous statement that the *intention* is for `Instant` to be thread-safe.  It would be laughable to claim that was a spec mistake, after 4 major releases of Java.

Comment: More laughable than a JVM bug? What if the class was refactored and they dropped a `final`?

Comment: No.  A JVM bug is a bug.  They do happen.  My point is that in this case it would be (hypothethically) laughable / intellectually dishonest for them to claim this (hypothetical situation) was a javadoc bug *rather than* a JVM bug.  (Now I'm not saying that is always the case.  But in **this** case ....)

Comment: I'm sure they happen. But it's not obvious to me that a class not behaving to spec necessarily indicates a JVM bug.

Comment: It depends on how clear the spec is.  In this case, the spec is crystal clear.  Totally unambiguous.  It is indisputable what the spec writer meant.  (Except if you got a clever Oracle lawyer and an ignorant jury :-) )